# Difference between lein repl (-main "something") and lein run "something")

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Newbie Clojure and leiningen question:

Given the code snippet in my project below, this works from the lein repl :

```
==> (-main "something")
```

produces the expected "Command: something ... running ... done"
but doesn't work from the command line:

```
me pallet1]lein run "something"
```

produces "Command: something ... error: not resolved as a command"

Why? / how do I fix it?

To reproduce:

```
lein new eg
```

Then edit the generated project file, adding `:main eg.core` to define the main function, and edit the generated src/eg/core.clj file, and paste this in:

core.clj

```
(ns eg.core)
(defn something [] (println "Something!"))

(defn run-command-if-any [^String commandname]
    (printf "Command: %s ..." commandname)
    (if-let [cmd (ns-resolve *ns* (symbol commandname))] 
      (
        (println "running ...") (cmd) (println "done.")
      )
      (println "error: not resolved as a command.")
    ))
(defn -main [ commandname ] (run-command-if-any commandname))
```

Then

```
lein repl
eg.core=> (-main "something")
```

works (ie prints "Something!) , but 
    lein run something
doesn't (ie prints the "error: not resolved" message)

Comment: What is `something`? Where do you define it? If it's not in your clj file and your defined it in repl that running `lein run` doesn't know about it because it only reads your clj file.

Comment: If run both code in REPL it gives me "not resolved".

Comment: As Nikita says, you don't have repl/something defined in your example code. Also, even if you do define that, it'll give a NullPointerException since you're trying to call the result of (println "running")

Comment: Okay, I added the defn of something to the code quote. The real code has several functions (to do with getting to grips with palletOps) my goal is to run one of them from the command line.

Comment: I guess the alternative question I could have asked is  "How do I pass the name of a Clojure function as a command line argument and have it run? The run-command-if-any is supposed to do that, but at the moment only works when I do it within the repl, not from the command line

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where the NullPointerException was coming from

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that when you run it from lein your default namespace is "user" namespace:

```
(defn -main [ commandname ] (println *ns*))
```

Prints `#<Namespace user>`. So it doesn't contain `something` function because it is from another namespace. You have several choices:

1. Pass fully qualified function name: `your-namespace/something` instead of `something`.
2. Use `your-namespace` instead of `*ns*`: `(ns-resolve 'your-namespace (symbol commandname))`
3. Change namespace to `your-namespace` in `-main`.

Example of method 3:

```
(defn -main [ commandname ] 
   (in-ns 'your-namespace)
   (run-command-if-any commandname))
```

Also you if you want to call several functions one by one you should use do:

```
(do (println "Hello")
    (println "World"))
```

Not just braces like `( (println "hello") (println "World"))`

Answer (score 2):

the [lein exec plugin](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-exec) is very useful for scripting such things in the context of a project. I have used this extensively for writing Jenkins jobs in clojure and other scripting situations

```
lein exec -pe '(something ...) (something-else) (save-results)'
```